# Conditional Format of cell based on the format of another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, libreoffice-calc

Referring to screen shot, I want to programmtically format a cell like so:

```
If cell B4 and cell F4 are both red text, then format cell J4 to be red text.
```

(and similarly for all other cells).

I see one can format a cell based on the value contained in another cell, but I'm not finding that you can base it on the format of the cell. Is this possible?

[image]

---

Add more info. As stated, I can see how to base a condition on a value of a cell. [Here is an example](https://www.exceltip.com/formating-in-vba/conditonal-formatting-using-microsoft-excel-vba.html):

```
Sub FormatUsingVBA()
Dim rng As Range
Dim lastRow As Long
lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
Set rng = Range("C2:C" & lastRow)For Each cell In rng
If cell.Value2 = "Adult" Then
Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, -2).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
ElseIf cell.Value2 = "KID" Then
Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, -2).Interior.ColorIndex = 4
ElseIf cell.Value2 = "Teenager" Then
Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, -2).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
Else
Range(cell.Address).Offset(0, -2).Interior.ColorIndex = 0
End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

So it has a condition based on the value in a cell (`If cell.Value2 = "Adult"`). I want base it on the format of a cell and I don't see how to do this.

---

Entering macro command in cell

[image: Cell Formula]

[image: Macros]

Comment: It looks like you are asking about Excel VBA. In that case, you should remove the tag for LO Calc. Or do you want to know how this would translate into LO Basic? It would need to be rewritten entirely.

Comment: I can work with Excel or Calc.

Answer (score 1):

From https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/How_Tos/Calc:_STYLE_function:

> There is no direct way to determine (in a formula) what formatting has been applied to a cell.

So it sounds like you need to write a macro, at least for Calc. No idea about MS Excel.

**EDIT**:

From my answer at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/154239/get-color-of-text-in-cell/.

```vb
Function RGBprobe(x , y, optional z)
    Dim RGBarray(1 to 3)
    oDoc = ThisComponent
    oSheet = oDoc.Sheets(0)
    'Decreasing coordinate values by 1 because BASIC starts numbering with 0.
    If NOT IsMissing(z) Then oSheet = oDoc.Sheets(z-1)
    oCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition(x-1,y-1)
    CBkC = oCell.CharColor
    RGBarray(1) = Red(CBkC) : RGBarray(2) = Green(CBkC) : RGBarray(3) = Blue(CBkC)
    RGBprobe = RGBarray
End Function
```

For example, a formula that checks the color of cell `A1` is `=RGBPROBE(1;1)`. To see all three returned values, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> for the array formula result.

Comment: Yes, write a macro, that is what I meant by programmatically. Sorry if this was not clear. I've added more info to the question.

Comment: Thanks. So following the instructions in the link, I entered the call to the macro in the cell but it seems to be taking it as literal text, not a formula. What do I need to do? (see addendum to question)

Comment: It looks like you have a space in front of the formula, which apparently causes Calc to treat it as text.

Comment: I just notice the red squiggle line under RGBProbe in the cell. It doesn't know what it is.

Comment: If the function wasn't defined, then it would say `#NAME?`. I think the problem is a space instead. You did add the function in `My Macros`, correct?

Comment: You can see the function defined in the screenshot.I don't see any space. Somehow I got it to run and I get this error: BASIC syntax error. Unknown data type Range.

Comment: If you haven't worked with user-defined functions before, try this example: https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/User-Defined_Functions.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105946/discussion-between-jim-k-and-al-lelopath).